# Unable to query SecKeyChain for identity

Tags: ios, ssl, xamarin.ios, xamarin, certificate

I'm adding identity to SecKeyChain and then I'm trying to get it back using SecKeyChain.QueryAsConcreteType. But with any SecRecord query I get SecStatusCode.Param. Looks like the problem is that when I use new SecRecord(SecKind.Identity) it doesn't put kSecClass to dictionary that is Ok for adding but fails querying.

```
public SecRecord(SecKind secKind) { 
   IntPtr num = SecClass.FromSecKind(secKind); 
   if (num == SecClass.Identity) this._queryDict = new NSMutableDictionary(); 
   else this.queryDict = NSMutableDictionary.LowlevelFromObjectAndKey(num, SecClass.SecClassKey); 
}
```

If I'm wrong, please explain me how to add identity to SecKeyChain and then retrieve it.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*note: copy-pasted from [bug report](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=24972), it will be easier to google from here*

Unlike other classes the API is not symmetric for `SecIdentity`. Furthermore in this case the return value (`SecStatusCode`) is not trustworthy.

The current *best* (not using too many `IntPtr` or reflection) way to retrieve a `SecIdentity` is to do the following:

```
using (SecRecord rec = new SecRecord (SecKind.Identity)) {
    // the next line is the workaround
    (rec.ToDictionary () as NSMutableDictionary) ["class"] = new NSString ("idnt");

    SecStatusCode code;
    var match = SecKeyChain.QueryAsConcreteType (rec, out code);
    Assert.That (code, Is.EqualTo (SecStatusCode.Success), "QueryAsRecord-2");
    Assert.NotNull (match, "match-2");
}
```

That will set back the `class` before doing the query and return the identify.

A future version of XI will ensure that a simpler

```
using (SecRecord rec = new SecRecord (SecKind.Identity)) {
    ...
}
```

can be used for both adding and querying SecIdentity to/from the key chain.

Comment: Thanks, but that is my issue :) I should've added link here.